# Saving API response in React Context API and Redirect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

In my login page after getting the email and password, I sent them through `Axios` `post` request to validate and generate a `JWT web token` and with that token I'm calling another `Axios` `get` request to fetch some data (packs). To do this I have used chaining and all these are happening in `handleSubmit`. I've also used `context api` to save all the API response and later use it on different pages. But after submitting the form data, I'm getting the response back in console log but the `packs` are not set as payload which I've called through dispatch in the second `Axios` request. Though the `loggedIn` is getting set to `true` but `packs` is returning `undefined`. Where it should've contained an array of 3 objects. I've also used `Redirect` from `react-router-dom` and if the `loggedIn` is `true` (which it is after submitting the form) it should take me to the homepage or `{/}`. It is also not working. [The API Response after clicking submit](https://ibb.co/KsfvdQC)

**Login.js**

```
const [{ packs, loggedIn }, dispatch] = useAppContext();
  console.log(packs);
  console.log(loggedIn);

  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const data = {
      email: email,
      password: password,
    };

    axios
      .post("https://playtoshi.totafantasy.com/api/auth/login", data)
      .then((res) => {
        localStorage.setItem("token", res.data.token);
        return axios.get("https://playtoshi.totafantasy.com/api/packs").then(
          (res) => console.log(res),
          dispatch({
            type: "GET_DATA",
            packs: res.data.packs,
            loggedIn: true,
          })
        );
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    if (loggedIn) return <Redirect to={"/"} />;
  };

  return (
    <div className="login__container">
      <form className="login__form" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <h3>Sign In</h3>

        <div className="form-group">
          <label>Email address</label>
          <input
            type="email"
            className="form-control"
            placeholder="Enter email"
            required
            onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
          />
        </div>

        <div className="form-group">
          <label>Password</label>
          <input
            type="password"
            className="form-control"
            placeholder="Enter password"
            required
            onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
          />
        </div>

        <div className="form-group">
          <div className="custom-control custom-checkbox">
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              className="custom-control-input"
              id="customCheck1"
              style={{ marginRight: "5px" }}
            />
            <label className="custom-control-label" htmlFor="customCheck1">
              Remember me
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>

        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary btn-block">
          Submit
        </button>
        <p className="forgot-password text-right">
          Forgot <a href="/">password?</a>
        </p>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Login;
```

**Reducer.js**

```
export const initialState = {
  packs: [],
  loggedIn: false,
};

export const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "GET_DATA":
      return {
        ...state,
        packs: action.packs,
        loggedIn: true,
      };

    default:
      return { ...state };
  }
};
```

**Context.js**

```
import React, { createContext, useContext, useReducer } from "react";

export const AppContext = createContext();

export const Context = ({ initialState, reducer, children }) => {
  return (
    <AppContext.Provider value={useReducer(reducer, initialState)}>
      {children}
    </AppContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const useAppContext = () => useContext(AppContext);
```

Comment: The API response image isn't available.

Comment: @Alimo https://ibb.co/KsfvdQC